# Selectivity.js html5 property not working selectivity.js classes. With the error in console

Tags: javascript, html

```
Selectivity.js
```

**html5 property not working selectivity.js classes. 
With the error in console**

> An invalid form control with name='listing_id' is not focusable.

This occurs because selectivity work this way that it hides the select tag and create a new select box with js and css which performs virtually same functionality as of select of html5 except when you want to make that field required it starts to popup with issues. As the error above it occurs when you make a hidden field mandatory Chrome wants to show error on that field but face issues.

Any work around solution for this problem.

Comment: "_the error above occurs when you make a hidden field mandatory_" So as a user there is a field I must enter data into but I cannot see it? Seems odd - either it should not be required or I should be able to see it.

Comment: that is what i tried to explain. Selectivity js plugin hide the existing field and create new input field and select box options with div stying. if i make that parent select box required this error occurs,. if anybody has used Selectivity.js liberary?